# Can I use digital certificate as user's license?

Tags: authentication, licensing, digital-certificate

We have a client-server application with paid license. Can we use a digital certificate for user login and still prevent them from using the same license on two different computers?

From what I've learned over the internet I think we can't do that and those certificates are made for safe communication between client and server but I want to be sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are made for different purposes ("communication" is involved but it's involved everywhere). The certificate and its private key can be copied to another computer unless they are stored on a special cryptographic hardware (smartcard or USB cryptotoken).

On the other hand, are you licensing the software per-user, per-computer or per-concurrent-use? Maybe you just don't need restrictions on the client side but instead check that there are no concurrent connections from the same user on the server.